# How to bulk-rename files with invalid encoding or bulk-replace invalid encoded characters?

Tags: linux, batch, encoding, bulk

I have a debian server and I'm hosting music for an internet radio station. I have trouble with file names and paths because a lot of files got an invalid encoding, for example:

```
./music/BÃ¤ndname - Some Title - additional Info/B�ndname - 07 - This Title Is Cörtain, The EncÃding Not.mp3
```

Ideally, I would like to remove everything that is not letters `A-Z`/`a-z` or numbers `0-9` or dash `-`/underscore `_`... The result should look like something like that:

```
./music/Bndname-SomeTitle-additionalInfo/Bndname-07-ThisTitleIsCrtain,TheEncdingNot.mp3
```

How to achieve this for a batch of a lot of files and directories?

I've seen this similar question: [bulk rename (or correctly display) files with special characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/bulk-rename-or-correctly-display-files-with-special-characters)

But this only fixes the encoding, I would prefer a more strict approach as described above.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're going to run in some problems if you want to rename files *and* directories at the same time. Renaming just a file is easy enough. But you want to make sure the directories are also renamed. You can't simply `mv Motörhead/Encöding Motorhead/Encoding` since `Motorhead` won't exist at the time of the call.

So, we need a depth-first traversal of all files and folders, and then rename the current file or folder only. The following works with GNU `find` and Bash 4.2.42 on my OS X.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
find "$1" -depth -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
  d="$( dirname "$file" )"
  f="$( basename "$file" )"
  new="${f//[^a-zA-Z0-9\/\._\-]/}"
  if [ "$f" != "$new" ]      # if equal, name is already clean, so leave alone
  then
    if [ -e "$d/$new" ]
    then
      echo "Notice: \"$new\" and \"$f\" both exist in "$d":"
      ls -ld "$d/$new" "$d/$f"
    else
      echo mv "$file" "$d/$new"      # remove "echo" to actually rename things
    fi
  fi
done
```

You may change the regex by using `new="${f//[\\\/\:\*\?\"<>|]/}"` if you want to replace anything that Windows cannot handle.

Save this script as `rename.sh`, make it executable with `chmod +x rename.sh`. Then, call it like `rename.sh /some/path`.

Make sure to resolve any file name collisions (“`Notice`” announcements).

If you're **absolutely sure** it does the right replacements, remove the `echo` from the script to actually rename things instead of just printing what it does.

To be safe, I'd recommend testing this on a small subset of files first.

---

#### Options explained

To explain what goes on here:

- `-depth` will ensure directories are recursed depth-first, so we can "roll up" everything from the end. Usually, `find` traverses differently (but not breadth-first).
- `-print0` ensures the `find` output is null-delimited, so we can read it with `read -d ''` into the `file` variable. Doing so helps us deal with all kinds of weird file names, including ones with spaces, and even newlines.
- We'll get the directory of the file with `dirname`. Don't forget to always quote your variables properly, otherwise any path with spaces or globbing characters would break this script.
- We'll get the actual filename (or directory name) with `basename`.
- Then, we remove any invalid character from `$f` using Bash's string replacement capabilities. Invalid means anything that's not a lower- or uppercase letter, a digit, a slash (`\/`), a dot (`\.`), an underscore, or a minus-hyphen.
- If `$f` is already clean (the cleaned name is identical to the current name), skip it.
- If `$new` already exists in directory `$d` (e.g., you have files named `resume` and `résumé` in the same directory), issue a warning. You don't want to rename it, because, on some systems, `mv foo foo` causes a problem.  Otherwise,
- We finally rename the original file (or directory) to its new name

Since this will only act on the deepest hierarchy, renaming `Motörhead/Encöding` to `Motorhead/Encoding` is done in two steps:

1. `mv Motörhead/Encöding Motörhead/Encoding`
2. `mv Motörhead Motorhead`

This ensures all replacements are done in the correct order.

---

#### Example files and test run

Let's assume some files in a base folder called `test`:

```
test
test/Motörhead
test/Motörhead/anöther_file.mp3
test/Motörhead/Encöding
test/Randöm
test/Täst
test/Täst/Töst
test/with space
test/with-hyphen.txt
test/work
test/work/resume
test/work/résumé
test/work/schedule
```

Here is the output from a run in debug mode (with the `echo` in front of the `mv`),
i.e., the commands that would be called, and the collision warnings:

```
mv test/Motörhead/anöther_file.mp3 test/Motörhead/another_file.mp3
mv test/Motörhead/Encöding test/Motörhead/Encoding
mv test/Motörhead test/Motorhead
mv test/Randöm test/Random
mv test/Täst/Töst test/Täst/Tost
mv test/Täst test/Tast
mv test/with space test/withspace
Notice: "resume" and "résumé" both exist in test/work:
-rw-r—r--  …  …  test/work/resume
-rw-r—r--  …  …  test/work/résumé
```

Notice the absence of messages for `with-hyphen.txt`, `schedule`, and `test` itself.

Comment: You might want to add logic to handle the case where the destination of the `mv` already exists, which can happen (1) if you have files that are already clean (resulting in `mv foo foo`), or (2) if you have files with the same name except for the special characters (e.g., `mv Encöding Encoding`, where you already have an `Encoding` file in addition to `Encöding`).

Comment: Good idea, thanks. Any specific suggestions on what to do in that case? Granted – achieving this in a clean and sane manner is harder than it seems at first. If you have something, feel free to edit of course.

Comment: I don’t believe it makes sense to think about handling the collisions automatically –– just identify them to the user and let him handle them.  I’ve edited your answer, as you suggested.

Comment: +1 for using the example with "Encöding" Too much fön!:-)

Comment: I used this script but changed the regex to
`new="${f//[\\\/\:\*\?\"<>|]/}"` so that it only removes invalid Windows characters and retains valid ones like spaces, ampersands, commas etc. Very useful, thank you!

Answer (score 16):

I know that it's not exactly what you wanted, but if you know the original encoding, perhaps you can use [`convmv`](http://www.j3e.de/linux/convmv/man/) to change the encoding to UTF-8, which should fix most problems.

This worked for me on a folder with some invalid-encoded Polish filenames:

```
convmv -f cp1250 -t utf8 -r .
```

Note that this command doesn't actually rename anything; add `--notest` option to really rename the files.

Comment: For those who have a static set (or don't have a diverse mix of charsets), the `convmv` option is amazingly simple and perfect. For OP, having a potential multitude of charsets, this would could be merged with the other answer, since `convmv` seems to know when it or when it doesn't encounter the correct format. By looping through the charsets, via `convmv --list`, one would get them properly encoded.

Comment: By this I mean, if, as OP, runs a Debian server, one certainly would assume UTF8 these days, in which case, one can keep the original letters. I had the a folder of some nordic chars, and used: `convmv -t utf8 --nfc -f iso-8859-1 --notest -r .` – The `--nfc` was to conform to Linux ahead of OS X or so, simply typing `convmv` gives up the (useful) options.

Answer (score 0):

I know, you asked about renaming.

But you can dodge the problem quite easily using software like [MusicBrainz Picard](https://picard.musicbrainz.org/).

It is capable of identifying music (audio fingerprinting), downloading all the necessary data (including cover images, where available) from the huge [MusicBrainz](https://musicbrainz.org/) database and moving the files around so that your collection can fit any pattern you like.  I'm using it for years and it always worked perfectly with anything from Cyrilic to Arabic; and of course (at least for Latin-based scripts) it can also do the conversion to ASCII.

With this approach it does not really matter how messy/badly named your collection really is, as long as the files are readable and complete.

(Did I mention it's free?  Both as in free speech and as in free beer?  Both the software and the database..?)