# Block rename files with wrongly encoded filenames in Windows

Tags: windows, batch, encoding, bulk

I have a large number of files that (due to some multi-stage transport) have wrong filenames. For example a file that *should* be named

> Τεχνικός Di 04.02.2014 23_43.msg

is currently named

> +ñ+Á¤ç+¢+¦+¦¤î¤é Di 04.02.2014 23_43.msg

I *suspect* that the funny letter sequence is in fact a misinterpreted UTF-8 encoding of the intended filename.

I am aware of [How to bulk-rename files with invalid encoding or bulk-replace invalid encoded characters?](https://superuser.com/questions/538161/how-to-bulk-rename-files-with-invalid-encoding-or-bulk-replace-invalid-encoded-c) but my problem is about Windows, and any global replacement (e.g., by underscores) would not be ok; I do need the "correct" characters.